# Cant use jQuery's connectWith to join sortable div

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery's `sortable` function to allow the user to rearrange the order of divs. When the user clicks the button, a popup div appears.

I have tried to use the `connectWith` function to allow the user to drag this popup div into the list of divs, however it doesn't move to fit inbetween them - instead, it stays over them. Could this have anything to do with the `z-index`?

```js
$("#click").on("click", function() {
  $("#sortable1").show();
});

$('#sortable1, #sortable2').sortable({
  axis: 'y',
  connectWith: '.first',
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 13%;
  width: 85%;
}

div.div {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-top: 7.5px;
  margin-bottom: 7.5px;
}

.popup {
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="sortable1" style="display: none;">
  <div class="popup">
    <h2>RED</h2>
    <p>When his peaceful life is threatened by a high-tech assassin, former black-ops agent Frank Moses reassembles his old team in a last ditch effort to survive and uncover his assailants.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">

  <button id="click">Click me</button>
  <br>
  <br>

  <div id="sortable2" class="first">

    <div class="div">
      <h2>Deep Impact</h2>
      <p>Unless a comet can be destroyed before colliding with Earth, only those allowed into shelters will survive. Which people will survive?</p>
    </div>

    <div class="div">
      <h2>The Adjustment Bureau</h2>
      <p>The affair between a politician and a contemporary dancer is affected by mysterious forces keeping the lovers apart.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="div">
      <h2>Lord of the Flies</h2>
      <p>Stranded on an island, a group of schoolboys degenerate into savagery.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

*JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o0exme4f/*

Here is the **expected output** (when you drag the div saying 'drag me', you can see that it goes in between the divs saying 'example') - this example doesn't use a popup:

```js
$("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
  connectWith: ".first"
});
```

```css
div.ex {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="sortable1" class="first">
  <div class="ex">Example</div>
  <div class="ex">Example</div>
  <div class="ex">Example</div>
  <div class="ex">Example</div>
</div>

<p>
  Drag this div into the set above:
</p>

<div id="sortable2">
  <div class="ex">drag me</div>
</div>
```

*JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5ayf2yva/*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered similar problem a while ago. This is due to the position attribute you have applied to the `popup`. You should remove the `position` attribute from the `popup` css which is conflicting with the `sortable` or change the value to `static`. The sortable library does not work on absolutely positioned items.

```
.popup {
 width: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6v2d3dow/1/)

Comment: Ah, this seems to do it! But, without `position: absolute`, the position of the popup has now moved to the top of the page (`top: 20%` is no longer working). Any way to prevent this?

Comment: Also, `z-index: 1` seems to no longer be applied when removing `position: absolute` as the popup's content is going behind the divs which are already there.

Comment: @TheCodesee ohhh. I will try to look for a workaround.

Comment: I found out that setting the `position` to `relative` solves the `z-index` issue, but still not the `top` issue.

Comment: @TheCodesee Found this blog http://www.nightcrawler.ro/2014/01/jquery-sortable-with-absolute-position.html . Try using this. Maybe this is what you need.